# Javascript only changing every second element in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, dom, appendchild

I have written the following code, which should replace a value evaluating to either 0 or 1 inside the for-loop. But it only changes every second element in the table to correspondent switch element. What am I doing wrong here? I tried the code with `$("td[headers='blub']").eq(i).text("false") \.text("true")` and it changed every value correctly... so it has something to do with the appendchild... I also tried to remove the child after every iteration but not worked properly

```js
var length = $("td[headers='blub']").text().length;

for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
  if ($("td[headers='blub']").eq(i).text() == 1) {
    let la = document.createElement("LABEL");
    la.className = "switch";
    let x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    let sp = document.createElement("SPAN");
    sp.className = "slider round";

    x.checked = true;
    la.appendChild(x);
    la.appendChild(sp);

    $("td[headers='blub']").eq(i).replaceWith(la);
  } else {
    let la = document.createElement("LABEL");
    la.className = "switch";
    let x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    let sp = document.createElement("SPAN");
    sp.className = "slider round";

    x.checked = false;
    la.appendChild(x);
    la.appendChild(sp);

    $("td[headers='blub']").eq(i).replaceWith(la);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `text().length` gets the number of code points in the string value of `$("td[headers='blub']")`, whereas `$("td[headers='blub']").eq(i)` gets the `i`th element that matches `"td[headers='blub']"`. Two very different things.

Comment: yes, I am using this statement because `$("td[headers='blub']").text().length` gives me number of rows, and `$("td[headers='blub']").eq(i)` I am going through every single one of the rows @HereticMonkey

Comment: Why DOM methods _and_ jQuery? Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: jQuery saves you from a `TypeError` because `i` will be "out of bounds" in the last round

Comment: No, I'm telling you that `$("td[headers='blub']").text().length` gets you the length of the text in those cells, not the number of rows. If you want the number of rows of a `table` element, you search for `tr` (table row) elements.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok yeah thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- The `length` variable is set to the length of a *string*, not to the number of matching *DOM elements*.
- A `for` loop should go to `< length`, not `<= length`
- The effect you describe is the consequence of replacing `td` elements with something else, and so you reduce the number of matches with `$("td[headers='blub']")` making `.eq(i)` skip the next element that you expected to get.
- *Replacing* `td` elements with other types of elements will lead to invalid HTML. You should *keep* the `td` elements and change their *content* instead.
- You mix jQuery with non-jQuery methods. If you use jQuery, go all the way.

Here is what I would suggest:

```
$("td[headers='blub']").each(function () {
    let checked = $(this).text().trim() == "1";
    $(this).text("").append(
        $("<label>").addClass("switch").append(
            $("<input>", { type: "checkbox", checked }),
            $("<span>").addClass("slider round")
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Yeah I am new to jquery and javascript so I did a mixture. Your code snippet works perfectly!